# Passing extra Intent information from Activity to View

Tags: android

I have an activity that is launched from another activity through an intent. The intent carries an extra "id" information. Now, the launched activity has a custom view (actually, a extension of LinearLayout class). I want to access the "id" information in the custom view. Can the activity pass that value to its contained view? Or can the view get a handle to the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your custom View class can get a reference to the Activity it is contained in. Every View has a getContext() method which returns the Context the View is running in (i.e. your Activity).

Comment: Can you then just cast the context to your Activity, and use that to access the Activity's methods and member variables?

Answer (score 4):

YES,

First you have pass id with the intent  like

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sample.class);
i.putExtra("id", id);
startActivity();
```

it pass the value to sample class

here

```
String i=getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("id").toString();
```

& you can use this id in your custom view

Answer (score 2):

make a method in your view that takes the id as a parameter, and then call that method from your activity.